# Ionic open Popover from another component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to be able to open an Ionic popover from another component(which doesn't have a module).
I trued adding it in the exports in the page module but that doesn't work.

This is show it is

Page->Component->Popover(the popover gets called from a component click)

Does anyone know any solution or what i could do to get this flow to work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the popover to the pages entry component and declarations fixed it