# Ionic open a Popover from another component within a page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I know that this question already exists here: [Ionic open Popover from another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927259/ionic-open-popover-from-another-component)
but I don't get the solution.

I have a page which includes a component for the toolbar which has an button. This button should trigger a function within the page. When I trigger the function from inside the page it works. I can also see that onInit the popoverController is filled, but later when the function is executed it's undefined.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
at HeaderComponent.push.6176.LocationSelectionPage.openAddLocation (location-selection.page.ts:92)
at HeaderComponent_ion_buttons_7_Template_ion_buttons_click_0_listener (template.html:14)
at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15285)
at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15323)
at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:560)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28664)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487)
```

The function looks like this:

```
openAddLocation() {
this.popover
  .create({
    component: LocationAddPage,
    cssClass: '',
    showBackdrop: true,
  })
  .then((popoverElement) => {
    popoverElement.present();
  });
```

}

I have another popover which works fine but it is triggered in the same page.

header.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() openAddLocation: Function;
  showBackBtn: boolean = false;
  showMenuBtn: boolean = true;
  path: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.path = this.router.url;
    if (/labsite-selection|retailers|location-selection/.test(this.path)) {
      this.showBackBtn = true;
      this.showMenuBtn = false;
    } else {
      this.showBackBtn = false;
      this.showMenuBtn = true;
    }
  }
}
```

components.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [HeaderComponent, SearchComponent],
  exports: [HeaderComponent, SearchComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

header.component.html

```html
<ion-header mode="md">
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>{{ title }}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button *ngIf="showMenuBtn" autoHide="false"></ion-menu-button>
      <ion-back-button
        *ngIf="showBackBtn"
        defaultHref="start"
      ></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons
      *ngIf="path.includes('location-selection')"
      slot="end"
      (click)="openAddLocation()"
    >
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: use `Observables`

Comment: You should register your `popover` for each component where do you use it.

Comment: @Danil I registered the popover in the page module and the component module (where all components are registered) and also in the popover page itself ofc

Comment: @kdc Can you add the code of the component (with imports and declarations) which produces the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, solution. You use your `app-header` component in this way:

```
<app-header [openAddLocation]="openAddLocation"></app-header>
```

and you have in your page this code:

```
openAddLocation() {
    this.popover.create({
        component: LocationAddPage,
        cssClass: '',
        showBackdrop: true,
    }).then((popoverElement) => {
        popoverElement.present();
    });
}
```

You should change it to this:

```
openAddLocation = () => {
    this.popover.create({
        component: LocationAddPage,
        cssClass: '',
        showBackdrop: true,
    }).then((popoverElement) => {
        popoverElement.present();
    });
}
```

**Explanation:**

In the first case, you pass a `Function`. This method does not pass `this` context to the component. When the component tries to call `@Input` function It calls with `this` of the component but not `this` of the page.

In the second case, you pass a closure. And here will uses `this` of the page in both calls.

**Another solution**

I think the first solution is easy to implement for you but I don't think that this is a good approach. I think It will be better to use `@Output` params instead of `@Input` to call the function.

In your `header.component.ts`:

```
- import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
+ import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

- @Input() openAddLocation: Function;
+ @Output() openAddLocation: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();
```

`header.component.html`:

```
- (click)="openAddLocation()"
+ (click)="openAddLocation.emit()"
```

Then you can use it on your page in this way:

```
<app-header (openAddLocation)="openAddLocation()"></app-header>
```

More info about `@Input` and `@Output` params in documentation: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: Thank you for the help. Very much appreciated.